# Cleaning Image field invalidates form in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to clean the photo submitted via an ImageField in a form using Pillow and in the following code in django 2.1

```
    def clean_photo(self):
        photo = self.cleaned_data.get("photo")
        if photo:
            if photo.size > 100000:
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Image is too large. Upload an image less than 100Kb in size')
            image = Image.open(photo)
            if image.size[0] > 250 or image.size[1] > 250:
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Image is too large. Upload an image less than 250x250 dimensions')
        return photo
```

When I dont have this method the form works fine and the picture gets uploaded and saved. However when using this method I get a

```
    The UserForm could not be changed because the data didn't validate.
```

error. Would appreciate any help as to why this is happening.

Thank you all

Sameer

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue ?

Comment: Seems to me your `clean_photo()` method is working and you uploaded a photo that causes it to raise a `ValidationError`. Why do you think it's not behaving as expected?

Comment: @dirkgroten when i upload an image that does not match the conditions listed in the `clean_photo()` method it does raise the `ValidationError` and the form is not submitted. However if I upload an image of correct size and dimensions  I get the error mentioned in the OP. The form is not saved coz it does not validate